# Object Expected - IE7 and 8

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer

When opening our client front end in IE, I get the error "Object Expected" and it points to the following when I debug. I've googled, but nothing straightforward yet, at least not specifics.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login_form").bind("submit", function () {
        processLogin();
        return false;
    })

    if ('<?php echo $_GET['email ']?>' != '' && '<?php echo $_GET['password ']?>' != '') {
        $('#login_form').submit();
    }
});
```

I know there is php in the js, so I attempted to put in a

```
document.write(<?php echo $_GET['email']?>)
```

in place of just the straight php, so that its differentiated. Though then it leads to another error based off this:

```
$("#description").toggle();
```

This is proof that IE is a pain. This works in Chrome, Safari and FF....

Ideas?

Comment: It might help if you view page source and paste the post-PHP Javascript. Also, you should probably escape your string in case someone uses a quote mark in their password: '<?php echo addslashes($_GET['password'])?>'

Comment: Can you post the source that's generated on the client side (i.e. view page source)?

Comment: you cant write php with javascript

Comment: @Dagon, but you can write javascript with PHP, which is what he appears to be doing.

Comment: @Stargazer712 - may bad.

Comment: I have successfully written PHP with JS before. Thats the odd part.

Comment: What line *specifically* is showing Object Expected?

Comment: As @Luke Dennis says, look at the generated code without any PHP content; if IE is pointing to a line number, it'll be a line number in the generated code, and is likely to be different from the line number in your actual source code with embedded PHP. It's therefore quite possible that you've been looking at the wrong bit of code all along.

Answer (score 0):

This line could be a problem (don´t know if it´s a copy-past problem...):

```
 if ('<?php echo $_GET['email ']?>' != '' && '<?php echo $_GET['password ']?>' != '')
```

It should be:

```
 if ('<?php echo $_GET['email']?>' != '' && '<?php echo $_GET['password']?>' != '')
```

The spaces after `email` and `password` will generate a warning (if they're turned on) that will lead to an auto-submit with php warnings as values.

Comment: In an effort to not have to type a ton of spaces, the post js code can be found here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25067517/post%20php.txt .. Pulled from Safari 5. and @Jeroen, there aren't spaces, paste issue. I did escape the 'email' and 'password' btw.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to debug Javascript in IE. If the web page throws an error, move this code farther up in your HTML. This will help you track down the specific Javascript code that is causing the problem.

If IE is still working even through it is throwing an error, this code can be useful to prevent people from seeing the error until you have a chance to fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function noError(){return true;}
window.onerror = noError;
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your quotes.

```
if ('<?php echo $_GET['email ']?>' != '' && '<?php echo $_GET['password ']?>' != '') {
```

Should be:

```
if ('<?php echo $_GET["email"]?>' != '' && '<?php echo $_GET["password"]?>' != '') {
```

Note the doublequotes around email.